# 'up' meaning each/apiece in sports?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I often hear sport scores being mentioned as '5 up' meaning the score is tied at 5 each/apiece.

[AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/up) gives:

> **up**  adv.
>
> ...
>
> 15. Each; apiece: *The score was tied at 11 up.*

Can anyone explain the basis of this usage? thanks

Comment: Are you sure it means tied? You would say 'X team is 2 up' if they were winning by a margin of 2.

Comment: i'm sure. it is definition #15 in the link below. just don't get the origin?

Comment: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/up

Comment: Could you [add that link and definition](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/507242/edit) to your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tennis: When and where did 30-all (and 15-all) start transitioning to the counterintuitive 30-up (and 15-up)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/457001/tennis-when-and-where-did-30-all-and-15-all-start-transitioning-to-the-counte)

Comment: thanks for posting the link...not a concrete explanation but helpful nonetheless:)